# Codeigniter and mysql - all data displayinging

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter and php.I made an uploading system.After uploading the file by user, i just want to display the user uploaded file.But Following code is displaying all the data of the mysql.How can user see only his uploaded data?Can someone suggest replacement

```
<?php
if (!empty($list) > 0) {
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        ?>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Manuscript ID</th>
                <th>Journal</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if (!empty($list) > 0) {
                foreach ($list as $row) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row->manu_id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->sub_title; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->title; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->created_date; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php
                            echo
                            site_url('user/removemanuscript/' . base64_encode($row->manu_id));
                            ?>" 
                               title="Soft Delete">Remove
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($row->final_status == 1) { ?>
                                <span class="label label-primary">Approved</span>
                            <?php } else if ($row->final_status == 2) { ?>
                                <span class="label label-
                                      danger">Disapproved</span>
                                  <?php } else { ?>
                                <span class="label label-warning">Pending</span>
                            <?php } ?>`enter code here`
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    <?php
    }
}
```

I am adding user controller for uploaded file.Please let me know

public function FinalManuscriptSubmit()
    {

```
    if ($this->Common_model->Is_User_Logged()) 
    {   
        $data=array();
        $joinClause=array();
        $whereClause=array();

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('user_logged_in');
        $u_id         = $session_data['id'];

        $sql="SELECT u.*,f.manu_id,m.journal_id,m.title,j.sub_title,f.created_date,f.final_status
        FROM user u 
        INNER JOIN final_manuscript f on f.user_id = u.user_id
        INNER JOIN manuscript m on m.manu_id = f.manu_id
        INNER JOIN journal j on j.sub_id = m.journal_id
            ";
        $data['list']=$this->Common_model->get_data_by_query($sql); 
        //print_r($data['list']);exit;
        $this->load->view('user/header');
        $this->load->view('user/showmanu',$data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer');

    }else{
        redirect('user/login');
    }
}
```

I will be thankful for your support.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific...

Comment: What is your database table structure? What do you call "uploaded data"?

Comment: this looks like the "view" component, we would need to see what your "controller" component is calling as well as some general table structure to give you any useful help. Help us to Help You.

Comment: you need to change your database query not view.

Comment: Use this if(!empty($list) && count($list) > 0)

Comment: i added controller, please help me to rectify my problem.